# Vsftpd passive reply with 0,0,0,0 address even with correct pasv_address

Tags: ftp, selinux, vsftpd

I have the following config in vsftpd

```
listen_ipv6=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
seccomp_sandbox=NO
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=1024
pasv_max_port=1048
pasv_address=<Elastic ip from amazon aws ec2 instance>
pasv_promiscuous=YES
```

However, when trying to connect to server using FTP I get this following warning,

```
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command: PWD
Response: 257 "/"
Command: TYPE I
Response: 200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command: PASV
Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (0,0,0,0,4,1).
Status: Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead.
Command: LIST
Response: 150 Here comes the directory listing.
Response: 226 Directory send OK.
Directory listing of "/" successful
```

If you see it enters the passive mode with this

> **Entering Passive Mode (0,0,0,0,4,1)**

I have no idea where is this coming from (or even what is it). I have SELinux  enforcing as well.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Kind Regards,
V

Answer (score 14):

It looks like a bug in vsftpd to me.

From the code, it looks like, vsftpd always sends the `0,0,0,0`, if the public `pasv_address` is set, and the server has a (local) IPv6 address.

To fix this, make sure the server does not listen on IPv6 address (what is the default behavior, which you are overriding by setting `listen_ipv6=YES`):

```
listen_ipv6=NO
listen=YES
```

The only other solution is removing the private IPv6 address, if it is possible in EC2.

Or use another FTP server, e.g. [ProFTPD](http://www.proftpd.org/).

---

To prove that this is indeed a bug:

`handle_pasv` in `postlogin.c`:

```c
int is_ipv6 = vsf_sysutil_sockaddr_is_ipv6(p_sess->p_local_addr);

...

if (tunable_pasv_address != 0)
{
  vsf_sysutil_sockaddr_alloc_ipv4(&s_p_sockaddr);
  /* Report passive address as specified in configuration */
  if (vsf_sysutil_inet_aton(tunable_pasv_address, s_p_sockaddr) == 0)
  {
    die("invalid pasv_address");
  }
}
else
{
  vsf_sysutil_sockaddr_clone(&s_p_sockaddr, p_sess->p_local_addr);
}
str_alloc_text(&s_pasv_res_str, "Entering Passive Mode (");
if (!is_ipv6)
{
  str_append_text(&s_pasv_res_str, vsf_sysutil_inet_ntop(s_p_sockaddr));
}
else
{
  const void* p_v4addr = vsf_sysutil_sockaddr_ipv6_v4(s_p_sockaddr);
  if (p_v4addr)
  {
    str_append_text(&s_pasv_res_str, vsf_sysutil_inet_ntoa(p_v4addr));
  }
  else
  {
    str_append_text(&s_pasv_res_str, "0,0,0,0");
  }
}
```

where the `vsf_sysutil_sockaddr_ipv6_v4` returns 0, if the `s_p_sockaddr` is not IPv6 (what it never is, when the `pasv_address` is set).

`sysutil.c`:

```c
const void*
vsf_sysutil_sockaddr_ipv6_v4(const struct vsf_sysutil_sockaddr* p_addr)
{
  static unsigned char pattern[12] =
      { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0xFF, 0xFF };
  const unsigned char* p_addr_start;
  if (p_addr->u.u_sockaddr.sa_family != AF_INET6)
  {
    return 0;
  }
  if (vsf_sysutil_memcmp(pattern, &p_addr->u.u_sockaddr_in6.sin6_addr, 12))
  {
    return 0;
  }
  p_addr_start = (const unsigned char*)&p_addr->u.u_sockaddr_in6.sin6_addr;
  return &p_addr_start[12];
}
```

Imho, the code is wrong. It works (and makes sense), when the IP address is "autodetected" from `p_sess->p_local_addr`, but fails, when the `pasv_address` address is used.

Consider reporting this to the author of vsftpd.

Comment: I don't know if this answer is right or not, but you should get credit for even caring enough to look.  It's ftp and no longer the 90s.

Comment: This saved me after 4 hours of research. Thanks!!

Comment: Thank you so much. Trying to figure this out was driving me mad setting up GitHub FTP Action to EC2 instance. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This seems like something they should have fixed years ago.

Comment: It can be silly mistake like I was doing (new to linux). We need to Restart service after making changes to config file! So make changes as suggested by [Martin Prikry](https://serverfault.com/a/821078/970650) and then restart service: sudo service vsftpd restart

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem with a server hosted on Aliyun.

I solved it by disabling listen_ipv6 and enabling listen in the config.

```
listen_ipv6=NO
listen=YES
```

I also specified my external IP using `pasv_address=`

Comment: I think the main key of this solution is pasv_address attribute without this it will not works btw thanks for sharing this.