# ftp server not responding after log in

Tags: ftp, router, network-attached-storage, asus

So my problem is that I have a FTP server running on my NAS behind a router.
When trying to log in through the NAS 192.168.1.X address I can connect and list the files but when accessing from my external static IP address I get the following:

```
MyLinuxUserName@myPC:~$ ftp my.example.com
Connected to my.example.com.
220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
220-You are user number 1 of 10 allowed.
220-Local time is now 12:32. Server port: 21.
220-IPv6 connections are also welcome on this server.
220 You will be disconnected after 10 minutes of inactivity.
Name (my.example.com:MyLinuxUserName): MyServerLoginName
331 User MyServerLoginName OK. Password required
Password:
230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> ls
200 PORT command successful
150 Connecting to port 47993
drwxr-xr-x    2 0          0                1024 Jun  2 11:39 .
drwxr-xr-x    2 0          0                1024 Jun  2 11:39 ..
drwxrwxrwx    1 0          0                  13 Jun  2 11:39 Volume_1
226-Options: -a -l 
226 3 matches total
ftp> cd Volume_1
250 OK. Current directory is /Volume_1
ftp> ls
200 PORT command successful
150 Connecting to port 47866
```

And then it's stuck.
For some reason it will allow me to authenticate but then it will not show me any other file contained in the Volume_1/ folder. (yes the correct permissions are set).

I'm not sure if I'm in the right place but I would sure appreciate some help in solving this really annoying error.

I am running a Dlink DNS-320L NAS behind a ASUS RT-N66U router with a static IP address aimed at the router with port 80, 20 and 21 forwarded to the NAS.

Comment: You've run into one of the many reasons that FTP has no business being used today. Use sftp instead and all will be well.

Comment: I admit I'm probably as smart as an Idiot when it comes to network but I'm not sure how.. since my NAS don't have a option to use that.... There is only a checkbox "Allow SSL/TLS connections only" in the FTP settings area...

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/555585/37681 for some background and a possible approach