# Can't transfer anything with FTP

Tags: iptables

I cant send or receive anything after connecting to FTP, but can remove files. I know that I didn't do a 'good job' with the iptables and now I need help.

Here is the output from `iptables -L -n -v`

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 16184 packets, 4360K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 930  149K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0           
 4672 3279K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    1    71 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:53
    1    60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:20000
   90  5200 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:10000
   28  1632 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
   39  2140 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
    1    60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:993
    1    60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:143
    1    60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:995
    3   160 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:110
    1    60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:53
    1    60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:587
    1    60 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:20
    5   300 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:21
   21  1240 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 6260 packets, 4251K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

If i change the input policy to accept everything works again but I dont want to do that. I tried to enable all the states for port 21 but still didn't work.

Comment: The firewalls rules you've shown are unhelpful, as they lack interface information.  Could you replace them with the output of `iptables -L -n -v`?

Comment: @MadHatter Okay i used iptables -L -n -v now hope that helps

Comment: FTP uses ports 20, 21, and the ephemeral port range which is typically 49152 to 65535.

Comment: I would also suggest this VSFTP specific answer of mine for some background: https://serverfault.com/a/555585/37681

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two answers([one](https://serverfault.com/questions/38398/allowing-ftp-with-iptables) and [two](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93554/iptables-to-allow-incoming-ftp)), both offer to use module `ip_conntrack_ftp`. Also in the second question, you could find answer with another solution with using `net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_helper=1`. Try those solutions.

Comment: the second answer did the trick! i have tried to enable states on port 21 but forgot to change it to port 20!   When i changed it there too RELATED,ESTABLISHED everything worked both sending and receiving