# Only 1 specific user gets the error 425 Can't open data connection for transfer of "/" when attempting to connect to my FTP server

Tags: windows, ftp, filezilla

Only 1 specific user gets the error 425 Can't open data connection for transfer of "/" when attempting to connect to my FTP server and he has attempting disabling firewall entirely adding the inbound/outbound rules for my port range and port 21, and nothing seems to work. My other clients can connect just fine.

```
(000094)8/13/2022 13:02:45 PM - (not logged in) (IP ADDRESS)> TLS connection established
(000094)8/13/2022 13:02:45 PM - (not logged in) (IP ADDRESS)> USER USERNAME
(000094)8/13/2022 13:02:45 PM - (not logged in) (IP ADDRESS)> 331 Password required for USERNAME
(000094)8/13/2022 13:02:45 PM - (not logged in) (IP ADDRESS)> PASS ***************
(000094)8/13/2022 13:02:45 PM - USERNAME (IP ADDRESS)> 230 Logged on
(000094)8/13/2022 13:02:45 PM - USERNAME (IP ADDRESS)> PBSZ 0
(000094)8/13/2022 13:02:45 PM - USERNAME (IP ADDRESS)> 200 PBSZ=0
(000094)8/13/2022 13:02:45 PM - USERNAME (IP ADDRESS)> PROT P
(000094)8/13/2022 13:02:45 PM - USERNAME (IP ADDRESS)> 200 Protection level set to P
(000094)8/13/2022 13:02:45 PM - USERNAME (IP ADDRESS)> PWD
(000094)8/13/2022 13:02:45 PM - USERNAME (IP ADDRESS)> 257 "/" is current directory.
(000094)8/13/2022 13:02:45 PM - USERNAME (IP ADDRESS)> TYPE I
(000094)8/13/2022 13:02:45 PM - USERNAME (IP ADDRESS)> 200 Type set to I
(000094)8/13/2022 13:02:45 PM - USERNAME (IP ADDRESS)> PORT 192,168,0,180,250,251
(000094)8/13/2022 13:02:45 PM - USERNAME (IP ADDRESS)> 200 Port command successful
(000094)8/13/2022 13:02:45 PM - USERNAME (IP ADDRESS)> MLSD
(000094)8/13/2022 13:02:45 PM - USERNAME (IP ADDRESS)> 150 Opening data channel for directory listing of "/"
(000094)8/13/2022 13:02:56 PM - USERNAME (IP ADDRESS)> 425 Can't open data connection for transfer of "/"
```

Comment: The `PORT 192,168,0,180,250,251` response shows a private use RFC 1918 IP-address from the 192.160.00/16 range. That might be a problem for an FTP client that is not in your internal network. (not quite applicable here maybe but this explains why that worries me: https://serverfault.com/a/979257/37681 )